# How to interpret the operators modulo/% and equality/== in the same line?

Tags: python, operators, operator-precedence

```
def has_lucky_number(nums):
      return any([num % 7 == 0 for num in nums])
```

Comment: First evaluates `num % 7` then checks if the result is equal to `0`

Comment: The percentage sign (`%`) is an operator that gives you the remainder of the euclidean division. For instance `10 % 3 == 1` because `10 = 3 * 3 + 1`.

Comment: Thank you guys! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list comprehension (that's the actual term you need to search for to see how this works, if you don't already know) `[num % 7 == 0 for num in nums]` will give you a list of `True` or `False` values, one for each number in the original list `nums`.

Each entry will be `True` if and only if the corresponding entry in `nums` is a multiple of seven, since `x % 7` is the remainder when you divide `x` by seven - if the remainder was zero then the number was a multiple. In terms of reading the expression itself, `num % 7 == 0` is functionally equivalent to `(num % 7) == 0`,

For example, an original list of `[1, 5, 7, 9, 14, 22]` would give you the resultant list `[False, False, True, False, True, False]`, since only `7` and `14` from that list satisfy the condition.

Following that, the expression `any(someList)` will return `True` if any of the elements of the list are true.

So the entire function as given will simply detect if *any* element in the list is a multiple of seven, apparently considered "lucky" in the context of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs for operation precedence
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

You can see in the table that mult/div (or % modulo) occurs before comparison (== and <=, etc.), so therefore '%' is evaluated before '==' is.