# What does sum(x%2==0) mean?? (python)

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, -1, 2, 5, 7])
print(sum(x%2==0))
```

This is the code, and I can't understand what does ' sum(x%2==0) ' mean.

Does it mean to sum even number?

I'm studying for school test and My professor said output of the above code is 1.
But I can't understand what does ' sum(x%2==0)' mean..

Comment: It counts the number of even elements in `x`.

Comment: You can look at the intermediate results if you split it out over several lines, you'll probably understand what's going on if you do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interpret the operators modulo/% and equality/== in the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67478632/how-to-interpret-the-operators-modulo-and-equality-in-the-same-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x % 2 == 0` will change your array to `[False, False, True, False, False]`
Because every element will be converted to a boolean, which represents, if the number is even or odd

Then the sum gets evaluated, where `False = 0` and `True = 1`
`0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, -1, 2, 5, 7])

# step 1: create an intermediate array which contains the modulo 2 of each element (if the element is even it will be True, otherwise False)
y = x % 2 == 0  # [False, False,  True, False, False]

# step 2: sum the intermediate array up. In this case the False values count as 0 and the True values as 1. There is one True value so the sum is 1
z = sum(y)  # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, here's an explanation. For Stack Overflow's purposes, I'm recommending to close this question as it's more coding help than a novel coding question.

The operations in this expresssion are as follows:

```
# operation 1
intermediate_result_1 = x%2

# operation 2
intermediate_result_2 = (intermediate_result_1 == 0)

# operation 3
sum(intermediate_result_2)
```

**Operation 1:** the modulo operator essentially returns the remainder when the first term is divided by the second term. Most basic mathematical operations (e.g. +,-,*,/,%,==,!=, etc) are implemented element-wise in numpy, which means that the operation is performed independently on each element in the array. Thus, the output from operation 1:

```
intermediate_result_1 = np.Array([1,1,0,1,1])
```

**Operation 2:** same for the equality operator ==. Each element of the array is compared to the right-hand value, and the resulting array has True (or 1) where the equality expression holds, and False (or 0) otherwise.

```
intermediate_result_2 = np.Array([0,0,1,0,0])
```

**Operation 3**: Lastly, the default `sum()` operator for a numpy array sums all values in the array. Note that numpy provides its own `sum` function which allows for summing along individual dimensions. Quite evidently the sum of this array's elements is 1.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` makes it easy for you to operate on the `array` object

as many answers already suggest that
`x%2==0` returns `[False, False, True, False, False]`

but if you are still confused then try to understand it like this

lets make a function which checks if a value is even or not.

```
def is_even(ele):
  return ele%2==0
```

then we use the `map` function

> map() function returns a map object(which is an iterator) of the
> results after applying the given function to each item of a given
> iterable (list, tuple etc.)
>
> NOTE: copied from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/)

then we take a simple list and map it with this function like so:

```
l=[1, -1, 2, 5, 7]  # this is not a np array
print(map(is_even, l))  # this prints [False, False, True, False, False]
print(sum(map(is_even, l)))  # this prints 1
```